# Insert a string into a bytea column

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, string-concatenation

I want to insert text data into a Postgres `bytea` column using the `concat` function or the `||` operator. I am getting an error

```
column "name" is of type bytea but expression is of type text
```

```
create table test(
   name bytea
);

insert into test(name) values(concat('abac-' , 'test123'));
insert into test(name) values('aa' || 'bb');
```

I am executing the insert inside a stored procedure. If want to add the argument like

```
(concat('abac-' , row.name , 'test123'));
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perform a type cast after concatenating the values:

```
INSERT INTO test (name)
   VALUES (CAST('abac-' || row.name || 'test123' AS bytea));
```

Note: The difference between `||` and `concat` is how they behave with NULLs.

Answer (score 3):

You need to cast both strings to bytea, for example:

```sql
insert into test(name) values('aa'::bytea || 'bb'::bytea);
```

Comment: Thanks.  am executing the insert inside stored procedure.  if want to add the dynamic variables inside row like  (concat('abac-' , row.name , 'test123')); how do i cast it?

Comment: `CAST(value AS type)` for example `CAST('abc' AS bytea)`.